# how to install php 5.5.12 on ubuntu while installing lampstack?

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, lamp

I have installed apache and mysql according to this tutorial, but I need to install php 5.5.12 [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) the `$ sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql` installs php 7.*

Comment: Easiest way to install 5.* PHP: `sudo apt-cache search php` Search package name for php 5

Comment: @RajenderJoshi there are only php7.* versions listed

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question.
https://askubuntu.com/a/756901/636504

extract:

**Using PHP PPA to coinstall PHP 5.6 with PHP 7.0**

There's an option to co-install PHP 5.6 packages using `ppa:ondrej/php`.

For more information, please see that answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/762161/309221

Extracted from link above:

> Assuming `libapache2-mod-php` is a suitable way to enable PHP in Apache for you, you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

> **Switch PHP version** ( Apache ):
>
> - from php5.6 to php7.0:
>     `sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart`
> - from php7.0 to php5.6:
>     `sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: php version php5.6 not available

Comment: out of curiosity... Why are you specifically limited to php5.5? What's in 5.5 that's not in 5.6 for you?

Comment: @JezEmery Insecure and deprecated methods. :p

Comment: @JezEmery well I have WAMP in windows and need completely move to linux therefore I need to install LAMP, for a existing project. The WAMP's php version in 5.5.12 therefore I am looking to instal exact same version in LAMP